# Office 2007 Ribbon Icons

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I've created Ribbon items (using XML) from the imageMSO names for built in Office 2007 icons.

However, I haven't been able to find imageMSO's for the icons with the Gallerys e.g. Inserting a Line chart brings up a list of icons for the different line chart templates.

Do those icons have an imageMSO which can be used in Ribbon XML??